# Object is not a function

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

**Problema:** Estoy tratando de exportar al `App.js` la función de `useToken` pero me da el error de que el objeto importado no es una función `Object is not a function`

## Código `useToken`

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function useToken() {

    const getToken = () => {
        const tokenString = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
        const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
        return userToken?.token
    };

    const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken());

    const saveToken = userToken => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));
        setToken(userToken.token);
    };

    return {
        setToken: saveToken,
        token
    }
};
```

## Código del `App.js`

```
    import useToken from "./components/useToken";
    import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
    import React from 'react';
    
    function App() {
      //Sesion token funciona como las cookies
      const [token, setToken] = useToken();
    
      if(!token) {
        return <Login setToken={setToken} />
      }
   ...
}
```

Comment: por que no estas contextualizando tu aplicación cuando utilizas token y sesiones ?

Comment: @Enzo Utilizo los tokens siempre y cuando no haya un set  de uno, lo mismo con las sesiones hasta que no se realiza el set del token no se guarda

Comment: como buena practica te recomendaría utilizar un `useContext` para poder manejar los tokens y sesiones desde allí, para que puedas tener un manejo mas sencillo de dichos datos